# How to detect url change in a new browser tab and get back the url?

Tags: javascript, typescript, knockout.js

I have a link that will open a url in a new tab like this:

```
<a href="#" target="teamViewer" style="color: deepskyblue"><span data-bind="text: connectorLoginLink, visible: shouldShowConnectorLoginLink, click: openTeamViewerUrl"></span></a>
```

As I want to detect the URL change in the new tab, I thought I had to use window.open(url) to open this link. Then, keep track of the new window.

In viewmodel:

```
public openTeamViewerUrl() {
    var newWindow = window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank', 'location=yes');
}
```

I want to set the opened tab to a newWindow object, then monitor it by using something like this:

```
var currentPage = newWindow.location.href;

    setInterval(function () {
        console.log(currentPage);
        if (currentPage !== newWindow.location.href) {
            // page has changed, set new page as 'current'
            currentPage = newWindow.location.href;

            console.log(currentPage);
            // do other thing...
        }
    }, 1000);
```

I got the error back when trying window.open: **Blocked opening 'http://www.google.com/' in a new window because the request was made in a sandboxed frame whose 'allow-popups' permission is not set.**

Really got stuck on this. How to by pass the allow-popups? Can this feature be achieved using other methods?

Comment: The browser blocks the pop up windows unless they were created form a user action, like a click. Open it inside an `addEventListener('click', function(){...}, false);`

Comment: Will try this. thanks for the reply. I am still doubtful whether this can be achieved. Seems like we cannot control the window of a different domain to listen to the url change. Not sure if there's any way to deal with that. Any thought?

Comment: Javascript don't have access on cross domain documents to prevent security problems. But I think events works, so newWindow.onload will fire if the url change.

Answer (score 2):

To detect a change of URL you can use javascript `unload` event on the `window`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/unload

```
window.addEventListener('unload', function(event) {
    console.log('Navigation occuring');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This can detect if an url gets navigated, but I could not get the changed url from the new window. I don't have permission to do something like this in javascript: newWindow = window.open(url);

Comment: In case someone needs this to detect oauth result in popup: browsers block getting cross-origin urls, so you have to set redirect uri to domain from which you getting location.href and then read oauth result